# Manga where the female lead is stabbed in the neck, but the blood flows back in and she heals immediately

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manga or manhwa had a female protagonist. She gets kidnapped and her neck bleeds is or snapped by assassin/kidnappers. There is is some kind of sorcery to restore her life. The blood flows back again, regenerating her neck (like an insane healing ability).

It came as a surprise to those who witnessed it including the male lead(?) or the the Empress, or Empress' kidnapper(?)

- It was fantasy not a horror genre, I read mainly romance fantasy.
- Probably acceptable for ages 13 or 17.
- It's definitely not a modern one.
- The setting was medieval where there was an Empress and Emperor, dukes, barons, etc. I don't recall there being a rival country mentioned.
- There was also magic and/or sorcery exist.
- The scene I'm thinking of was possibly a flashback to the character's younger days.
- I think the panels were colored, so it might be a manhwa.
- She might have been caught (by the kidnappers) in order to warn the male lead. The whole thing involved politics.
- The ability of the female lead was (I think) her innate ability to heal only herself.
- The male lead might have been a bastard child, one of the candidates to the throne. Had loss his mother maybe due to poison? ordered by the Empress, after which the male lead kept a low profile.
- The story was ongoing when I stopped.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the female lead's name? What was the setting (e.g. modern/fantasy/etc)? What was the male lead's name? Was the story in colour? Was it intended for adults (with sex/nudity/gore)? Was there a villain? What country was the Empress the empress of? Why was she stabbed in the neck? Who did the sorcery on her? Was this healing ability rare or entirely unknown in the setting? Other than healing, did she have any other powers? Why was she kidnapped in the first place?

Comment: I read years ago when I was young so I cannot recall anyones name. I don't even remember there appearance anymore. Im calling out for those who might have read it, thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: It was fantasy not a horror genre, I read mainly romance fantasy. Probably acceptable for ages 13 or 17. Its definitely not a modern one. A medieval setting where there are empress and emperor, duke, baron and so on. Where also magic or sorcery exist. The empress was there kingdom empress nor rival country.

Comment: The scene I think of was they was still on their younger days (maybe). I think the panels was colored, so it might be a manhwa.

She might have been caught in order to warn the ml, it involved politics. The ability of the fl, I think its her innate ability to heal only herself. When she woke up, I think she don't remember what happened.

Comment: The ml might be a bastard child, a one of the candidates in the throne. Had loss her mother maybe due to poison ordered by the empress of by any doing of the empress. Ml kept a  low profile.

As it was a long ago, I might mixed the stories I know and unconciously added some false memories. I only remember that particular scene of regeneration abulities as it was memorable. The manhwa was ongoing when I discontinued reading it.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead? Also, in roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: I am unable to remember. Roughly it was serialized at 2019/2020 when Valentine Kiss was still uncompleted.